# Using PHP Guzzle HTTP 6 to send JSON with data that is already encoded

Tags: php, json, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to send a POST request which contains a raw JSON string with the following header: `Content-Type: application/json`.

From looking at the docs, I can see that I can do something like this...

```
$data = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3];
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($guzzleConfig);
$options = [
    'json' => $data,
];
$client->post('http://example.com', $options);
```

My problem is that when I get to this point, `$data` has already been `json_encode`'d.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
$data = json_encode(['x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3]);
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($guzzleConfig);
$options = [
    'body' => $data,
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
];
$client->post('http://example.com', $options);
```

My question is: can I use the `json` option with an already-encoded array? Or is there a way for me to simply set the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: I know this is a bit sketchy but can't you pass `json_decode($data)` back into itself :/

Comment: I did consider that, but this piece of code is going to run thousands of times a day, and it seems un-necessary as there must be a way to do this. All I need to do is set a Content-Type header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to guzzle's docs http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json

You can pass the already encoded json directly into the body parameter

> Note This request option does not support customizing the Content-Type
>   header or any of the options from PHP's json_encode() function. If you
>   need to customize these settings, then you must pass the JSON encoded
>   data into the request yourself using the body request option and you
>   must specify the correct Content-Type header using the headers request
>   option.
>
> This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or multipart

Comment: I must have made a mistake when setting the Content-Type header, as when I just tried it again it worked! My mistake.

Comment: It looks like this is now deprecated: Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle also provides the `json` [Request option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json) which will automatically encode your content and set the `Content-Type` header.  More information at the link.  In fact the example provided uses a PUT request.

```
$response = $client->request('PUT', '/put', ['json' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);
```

Comment: This is basically the code in the original question which they want to *not* use.